# Best way to handle current user for Service in Angular with Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for authentication and firestore. I have an Angular project.
I found a way to get data from my collection with the current user. Either by passing the user (by first doing this.auth.currentUser as I do now) to my service method or simply use AngularFireAuth current user in the service. But to do this every time feels a little bit excessive. Is there a better way to have the user in a single property somehow or how should you go about it?

I have a service like this. I keep calling this.auth.currentUser.then(u => { ... Every single time I want to get the user. Is there a better way?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, CollectionReference } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  firestore: AngularFirestore
  constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore,
    public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.firestore = firestore;
    
  create(item: item): any {
    console.log("add..")
    this.auth.currentUser.then(u => {
      item.author = u.uid;
      let referenceCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<item> = this.firestore.collection<item>('items', ref => ref.where('author', '==', u.uid));
      return referenceCollection.doc(item.id).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)));
    })
  }
}
}
```

Maybe like store the currentuser in a property accessible from the service which is set when the application is opened? I am not sure how to go about implementing such method though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just store the user on the first query, (and then only overwrite it upon logout event):

```
myUser: any;
...

this.auth.currentUser.then(u => {
      myUser = u;
    })
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of this, great idea. I will try it out!